# Convert NodeList BACK to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, docx

I'm using [docx.js](http://blog.innovatejs.com/?p=184), which converts docx to html5 in the browser. The function `convertContent` outputs a `NodeList`. The issue is I need an HTML/XML string, not a `NodeList`.

Is there any way to convert a `NodeList` back into HTML? There are plenty of examples of going the other way or converting it to an array, but none on how to convert it back to HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear on your question (specifically `I need HTML5`)

If you want the string representation this will create a string of the html for each node in the list

```
var html = Array.prototype.reduce.call(nodes, function(html, node) {
    return html + ( node.outerHTML || node.nodeValue );
}, "");
```

**Update: fix textnodes showing up as undefined**

Try placing this in console on this site

```
var htmlstr = Array.prototype.reduce.call($("div")[43].childNodes, function(html, node) {
    return html + ( node.outerHTML || node.nodeValue );
}, "");

console.log(htmlstr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I'm having trouble finding any documentation for Array.prototype.reduce.call. How do I get the final output out of the function once it iterates through (I'm assuming it iterates). I've also updated my question to (hopefully) be more clear. All I mean was that I needed an HTML/XML string, not an array.

Comment: I'm just using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). As its not on the NodeList prototype I use `.call` in order to iterate the node list as if it was an array. You can write the same thing using a `for()` loop just wouldn't be as elegant

Answer (score 0):

Several [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) available for `NodeList`, one being `values()`.

```
let list = document.body.childNodes; //<-- returns NodeList
for (const value of list.values()) {
  myTarget.querySelector("#my-target-element").append(value);
}
```